# ImgUtil functions and colorAt

Tags: function, colorbox

how can I solve this problem?

Use the ImgUtil functions and colorAt to create a function makePicture: string -> figure -> int -> int -> unit
such that the name makePicture filename figure b h creates an image file named filename.png with an image of figure with width b and height h.
At points that have no color (cf. colorAt), the color must be gray (defined by the RGB value (128,128,128)).
You can use this feature to test your tasks.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please explain properly.

Comment: i have to solve this function with makePicture: string -> figure -> int -> int -> unit with visual studio code, but it feels difficult how to build the function, which code i should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let makePicture filename figur b h =`
`let bmp =`
//bmp = bit map
`ImgUtil.init b h`
`(fun (x,y) ->`
//x,y = the position in the map
`let c = match colourAt (x,y) figur with | None -> (128,128,128) | Some c -> c in ImgUtil.fromRgb c)`
//c = canvas

`let target = Filename + ".png"`
`do ImgUtil.toPngFile target bmp`
`do printfn "Wrote filbe: %s" target`

Comment: sorry for the jumbled way its set up. first time posting here, hopes it helps anyway.